# How to create a BooleanBinding against seleted item in a TableView in JavaFx

Tags: javafx-8

I would like to do the following, but am not able to make it work.

I have a table with the object MyCustomDTO and it has several properties on it.  I would like to disable an action when the property foo is a specific type.

I tried creating a BooleanBinding like so:

```
BooleanBinding booleanBinding = Bindings.createBooleanBinding(()->{
    boolean disableChangeType = false;
    MyCustomDTO dto = myTable.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
    if(dto == null || dto.getFoo().equals("VALUE")){
        disableChangeType = true;
    }
    return disableChangeType;
});
```

I tried this as both a field and a local variable and nothing worked.

```
changeButton.disableProperty().bind(Bindings.isEmpty(list).or(booleanBinding ));
```

Can this be done as a binding? This Binding seems to only evaluate one time, and then stays at that value, even though I have selected another item in the tableview.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your boolean binding will work if you tell it which observable object to watch for changes:

```
BooleanBinding booleanBinding = Bindings.createBooleanBinding(()->{
    boolean disableChangeType = false;
    MyCustomDTO dto = myTable.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
    if(dto == null || dto.getFoo().equals("VALUE")){
        disableChangeType = true;
    }
    return disableChangeType;
}, myTable.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty());
```

Answer (score -1):

I was able to make this work by doing two things:

1) Make the binding a field level

2) Add a selection listener on the selected property and invalidate the binding as follows

```
myTable.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((obs, ov, nv)-> booleanBinding .invalidate());
```